# Subset_problem is not giving correct result

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Can anyone please help why the output is not correct?
Given a set of distinct integers, nums, return all possible subsets (the power set).

```py
class Solution(object):
    sol =[]
    index = 0

    def subsets(self, nums):
        sol = []
        index = 0
        curr = []
        self.helper(nums, sol, index, curr)
        return sol

    def helper(self, nums, sol, index, curr = []):
        if index == len(nums)  or len(nums)== 0:
            sol.append(list(curr))
            return sol

        self.helper(nums, sol, index +1, curr)
        curr.append(nums[index])
        self.helper(nums, sol, index + 1, curr)


s = Solution()
print (s.subsets([1, 2, 3]))
```

real output = [[], [3], [3, 2], [3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3]]

expected output : [[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,3],[2],[2,3],[3]]

If I change the curr to string(it was list earlier) then it is working and giving correct result :

```py
class Solution(object):
    sol =[]
    index = 0

    def subsets(self, nums):
        sol = []
        index = 0
        curr = ""
        self.helper(nums, sol, index, curr)
        return sol

    def helper(self, nums, sol, index, curr):


        if index == len(nums)  or len(nums)== 0:
            print (curr, "===")
            sol.append(list(curr))
            return sol

        self.helper(nums, sol, index +1, curr)
        #append(nums[index])
        curr = curr + str(nums[index])
        self.helper(nums, sol, index +1, curr)


s = Solution()
print (s.subsets([1,2, 3]))
```

Comment: Add the example Input. the output, the expected output.

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? What exactly where your findings?

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain how is your code supposed to function?

Comment: yes , I tried. this version is working if I use string not list for curr.Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string and list examples are not identical: You re-assign `curr` in the string code and create new strings for each recursive call, but append to the same list in the list code, which means that you will allways carry around everything you've added, because you're using the same list over and over.

Your list code will work when you do what the string code does:

```
curr = curr + [nums[index]]
```

(Alternatively, pass `curr + [nums[index]]` to the second call to the helper function.

Comment: Thankyou. yes It's working. curr.append() will it be different than curr = curr + [nums[index]]?

Comment: Yes. After you say `curr.append(stuff)`, `curr` will be the same list, only with stuff appended. After you say `curr = curr + [stuff]`, curr will be a new list. There is no difference in the immediate recursion, but the difference shows in the parallel recursions once the current recusrion has returned: They will still see the stuff you've added elsewhere.

Comment: By the way, you can re-use the same list and `append` ne items, but then you must clean up your list after you've called the helper function by popping the last element off again: `curr.pop()`. (That's one of the pifalls of recursion and is related to not resetting the "visited" flag after probing a path in a maze-finding algo.)